# Using rsync from OneDrive folder to SharePoint always shows files are different

Tags: sharepoint, onedrive, rsync

I am trying to `rsync` some files from my OneDrive Business Account to our SharePoint (PowerPoint presentations, Word files,...). I am working locally in the OneDrive folder and when I am done, I want to push the files to our shared SharePoint (which is connected to the same OneDrive Business account). Basically, I want the folder in the SharePoint to be identical to the one on my OneDrive, if I execute this command.

I use the following command for this:

```
rsync -avh --delete --progress /Users/username/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Company-Name/sourcefolder/ /Users/username/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-FreigegebeneBibliotheken–Company-Name/dest_folder
```

I did this once and some folder and files that I already copied there manually were shown as different. When I did it again, the same folder and files are still different, but some are the same. I used `--itemize-changes` to check, what's the difference. It turns out, that all files that differ are MS Office files (`.docx`, `.xlsx`, `.pptx`, ...). Additionally, every folder containing such a file has a differing timestamp. So the exemplary output of `rsync -avh --delete --progress sourcefolder/ dest_folder -ni` is:

```
...
.d..t.... dir/subdir/
>f.s..... dir/subdir/file.docx
>f....... dir/subdir/file.pdf
>f....... dir/subdir/file.png
...
```

The office files on the SharePoint always have the same timestamp, but they are bigger. Additionally, even the files that are no different, but are in a folder with a different timestamp seem to get transferred anew (If I interpret the `>` at the beginning correctly.
I only want to copy new or changed files, but not all of them, and delete files, that I also deleted in my folder. One reason for this is that this would trigger a download for the other SharePoint user, which is not necessary. And the more files there are the longer the transfer will take.
Does anyone know, why this happens and how to prevent this?